# como faço para soma todos os números de cada linha e coluna?

Tags: vba

Estou tentando somar todos os números de cada linha e coluna. Tentei fazer conforme abaixo, porém não está dando certo.

```
ranger .ClearContents

For n = 1 To 10
For Z = 1 To 10

  Cells(Z, n) = Int(100 * Rnd())
  k = Cells(n, Z)

 If Int(k / 2) - k / 2 = 0 Then
        pares = pares + 1
    Else
        Impares = Impares + 1
    End If

    If k = 0 Then Zeros = Zeros + 1

    If k > 10 Then MaioresQuedez = MaioresQuedez + 1

Cells(12, 2) = pares & " números Pares"

Cells(14, 2) = Impares & " números Ímpares"

Cells(16, 2) = Zeros & " números Zero"

Cells(18, 2) = MaioresQuedez & " números maiores do que 10"

next z
next n
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: Não seria  k = Cells(Z,n) ?

Comment: está correto assim, eu só quero sabe qual comando usar para pode somar cada linha e coluna.

Comment: Veja se eu entendi. Você começa com a planilha limpa. Depois entra em um laço e começa atribuir valores aleatórios às colunas. Atribui um valor a célula Z, n. Na linha seguinte você atribui à variável K o conteúdo da célula  n, Z que nesse momento esta em branco. Esta correto isso?

Comment: já editei lá, deveria te feito outra pergunta!

Comment: Luana, você está abrindo várias perguntas muito parecidas ou muito próximas. Por favor, não faça isso. Mesmo que talvez vc tenha dúvidas diferentes, simplesmente colar o mesmo código não ajuda. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask].

Comment: Outra coisa: se você deseja somar um intervalo (range), por que não fez isso diretamente na planilha (selecionando as células ou usando a função [`SUM`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUM-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1))? Aliás, mesmo que você *precise* implementar algo em Excel, se tiver o intervalo também dá pra usar a função no código (veja [esse link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31081472/2896619)).

Answer (score 0):

Veja assim:

```
Dim totalpares
Dim totalimpares
Dim maioresquedez

totalpares = 0
totalimpares = 0
maioresquedez = 0

For n = 1 To 10
For Z = 1 To 10

  Cells(Z, n) = Int(100 * Rnd())
  k = Cells(Z, n)

 If Int(k / 2) - k / 2 = 0 Then
        pares = pares + 1
        totalpares = totalpares + k
    Else
        Impares = Impares + 1
        totalimpares = totalimpares + k
    End If

    If k = 0 Then Zeros = Zeros + 1

    If k > 10 Then
       MaioresQuedez = MaioresQuedez + 1
       maioresquedez = maioresquedez + K
    end if 


Cells(12, 2) = pares & " números Pares, totalizando " & totalpares

Cells(14, 2) = Impares & " números Ímpares, totalizando " & totalimpares

Cells(16, 2) = Zeros & " números Zero"

Cells(18, 2) = MaioresQuedez & " números maiores do que 10. Totalizando " &  maioresquedez

Next Z
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: nesse caso é o total, mas queria saber como ficar o total de cada linha e coluna ao lado. obrigada pela ajuda!